# beautifulsoup and mechanize to get ajax call result

Tags: python, ajax, beautifulsoup, mechanize, scraper

hi im building a scraper using python 2.5 and beautifulsoup
but im stuble upon a problem ... part of the web page is generating
after user click on some button, whitch start an ajax request by calling specific javacsript function using proper parameters

is there a way to simulate user interaction and get this result? i come across a mechanize module but it seems to me that this is mostly used to work with forms ...

i would appreciate any links or some code samples
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok so i have figured it out ... it was quite simple after i realised that i could use combination of urllib, ulrlib2 and beautifulsoup

```
import urllib, urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs_parse

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req  = urllib2.Request(url, data)
res  = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = bs_parse(res.read())
```

Comment: I am facing same issue ... pls help ...

what is `values`

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that easily. AFAIK your options are, easiest first:

1. Read the AJAX javascript code yourself, as a human programmer, understand it, and then write python code to simulate the AJAX calls by hand. You can also use some capture software to capture requests/responses made live and try to reproduce them with code;
2. Use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or some other browser automation tool to fetch the page on a real web browser;
3. Use some python javascript runner like [spidermonkey](http://code.google.com/p/python-spidermonkey/) or [pyv8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) to run the javascript code, and hook it to your copy of the HTML dom;

Comment: hi, first option wouldnt be that easy because the javascript is in packed version
thanks for the heads up i'll look over it first thing tommorow

Comment: @nabizan: that's why I also suggested usage of capture software on option 1

Comment: hi, so after a little digging on unpack javascript i find out what should i call and how. than it was quite easy (see my answer for more info)