# Not able to scrape content with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping with `Python` and `BeautifulSoup`.

I have to scrape this page.

http://www.starwoodhotels.com//sheraton/property/reviews/index.html?language=en_US&propertyID=115

From this page, I have scraped the address of hotel successfully, But I am unable to scrape the User Reviews section

Here is my code

```
hotel_link = "http://www.starwoodhotels.com//sheraton/property/reviews/index.html?language=en_US&propertyID=115"

hotel_page_html = requests.get(hotel_link,headers = header).text
hotel_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(hotel_page_html)

for hotel_address in hotel_page_soup.select("div#propertyAddressContainer ul#propertyAddress"):
  print("Address: "+hotel_address.select("li")[0].text)

print(hotel_page_soup.select("div.BVRRRatingNormalOutOf"))
```

As you can see, using the CSS Selector `div#propertyAddressContainer ul#propertyAddress`, I have got the address but am unable to scrape the `User Reviews` section.

I have checked the `Console` while page loads but I don't see anything that User Reviews are loaded by an AJAX call.

So how do I scrape the Reviews section?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5913539/2063058  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610112/beautifulsoup-and-mechanize-to-get-ajax-call-result

Comment: I need to see which is the URl fetching the reviews? I have searched in the page HTML but cannot find it. Can someone tell me the URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995713/2063058

Comment: i saw all urls via HTTP Fox but cant seem to find it

Comment: the site redirects to a mobile site if certain criteria don't match. What do you put in your "header" variable?

Comment: This is my `headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"}`

Comment: It's Beautiful**soup**.

Answer (score 1):

why are you making this so complicated?

just do,

```
soup.find("span",{"itemprop":"aggregateRating"}).text.encode('ascii','ignore').replace('\n',' ')

Out[]:
Rated 3.4 out of 5by 625 reviewers.
```

isn't that what you need?

Comment: in your case it would be `hotel_page_soup.find` instead of `soup.find`

Comment: It did not work ... I ahve posted answer myself .... thanks alot for your efforts though

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
rev = hotel_page_soup.find( "span",
                            { "itemprop": "aggregateRating" }
                            ).text.encode( 'ascii',
                                           'ignore'
                                           ).replace( '\n', ' ' )

for total_rating_score in rev.select( "span" ):
    print ( total_rating_score.string )
```

Comment: Your answer won't even work. `rev` is a string and that will never work with `rev.select` This is ridiculous. You ask questions and when someone answers you just minor modify to something that is not even right and post it yourself??